# If I delete messaging service in Twilio then it will also remove mobile number from it?

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api, msg, twilio-javascript

If I delete messaging service from Twilio then the mobile number is register will it also delete ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a support question about the internal operation of a third-party service.

Comment: Yes but if someone was facing the same So can share their experience .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a messaging service the number will remain in your account. To delete a number you need to explicitly release it, either in the UI or [using the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#delete-an-incomingphonenumber-resource).

Comment: Fantastic! If this answer helped, please do mark it as correct so that others can see it was right too. Thanks!

Comment: So Is there any priority that which we can do first like Release the number first and then delete message service or vice versa .

Comment: I believe if you release a number, then it will be removed from the messaging service number pool and if you delete the messaging service then all the numbers in the pool will no longer be in the pool. It doesn't matter which way around you do it to Twilio, you need to choose the order in which it works for your application.

Comment: So If I delete the message service then all the number attach with message service will also deleted .

Comment: No, if you delete a messaging service then the numbers will not be deleted. It will remain in your account.

Comment: How can we delete if any of number is linked on message service .

Comment: Loop through the numbers and use the Incoming Phone Numbers API to delete them: https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource